# Cannot access to Apache Tomcat/8.0.32 Manager App on OSX

Tags: macos, tomcat

I'm having a problem accessing to tomcat manager app on localhost. As I installed tomcat to my mac, it didn't ask to set username or password (as it does on windows). But if I try to login to manager app it requires both of them.

What I've tried so far:

1) I took the username and password from tomcat-user.xml and tried to login

```html
<tomcat-users xmlns="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml tomcat-users.xsd"
              version="1.0">
<!--
  NOTE:  By default, no user is included in the "manager-gui" role required
  to operate the "/manager/html" web application.  If you wish to use this app,
  you must define such a user - the username and password are arbitrary.
-->
<!--
  NOTE:  The sample user and role entries below are wrapped in a comment
  and thus are ignored when reading this file. Do not forget to remove
  <!.. ..> that surrounds them.
-->
<!--
  <role rolename="tomcat"/>
  <role rolename="role1"/>
  <user username="tomcat" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat"/>
  <user username="both" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat,role1"/>
  <user username="role1" password="tomcat" roles="role1"/>
-->
</tomcat-users>
```

2) Then I uncommented role and user tags (by default they are commented) and tried to login

```html
<tomcat-users xmlns="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml tomcat-users.xsd"
              version="1.0">
<!--
  NOTE:  By default, no user is included in the "manager-gui" role required
  to operate the "/manager/html" web application.  If you wish to use this app,
  you must define such a user - the username and password are arbitrary.
-->
<!--
  NOTE:  The sample user and role entries below are wrapped in a comment
  and thus are ignored when reading this file. Do not forget to remove
  <!.. ..> that surrounds them.
-->

  <role rolename="tomcat"/>
  <role rolename="role1"/>
  <user username="tomcat" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat"/>
  <user username="both" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat,role1"/>
  <user username="role1" password="tomcat" roles="role1"/>

</tomcat-users>
```

3) Then I added some extra lines to xml, that are described here https://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/TomcatOnMacOS under step 3 and tried to login

```html
<tomcat-users xmlns="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml tomcat-users.xsd"
              version="1.0">
<!--
  NOTE:  By default, no user is included in the "manager-gui" role required
  to operate the "/manager/html" web application.  If you wish to use this app,
  you must define such a user - the username and password are arbitrary.
-->
<!--
  NOTE:  The sample user and role entries below are wrapped in a comment
  and thus are ignored when reading this file. Do not forget to remove
  <!.. ..> that surrounds them.
-->

  <role rolename="tomcat"/>
  <role rolename="role1"/>
  <role rolename="manager"/>
  <role rolename="admin"/>
  <user username="tomcat" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat,admin,manager"/>
  <user username="both" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat,role1"/>
  <user username="role1" password="tomcat" roles="role1"/>

</tomcat-users>
```

but so far nothing has helped. Any suggestions how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

If you press cancel on the basic authentication that pops up it should list the roles you're missing/are needing.

I have this config for my tomcat 8:

```
<role rolename="manager-gui"/>
<role rolename="admin-gui"/>
<role rolename="manager-script"/>
<user username="admin" password="password" roles="manager-gui,admin-gui,manager-script"/>
```

Comment: Thanks! Yeap, so it does. In addition, in my case, I had to restart tomcat after adding new roles.

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since I've actively and willingly used the manager application, but there are two common caveats. One is written in the snippet that you copied in your question

```html
<!--
  NOTE:  By default, no user is included in the "manager-gui" role required
  to operate the "/manager/html" web application.  If you wish to use this app,
  you must define such a user - the username and password are arbitrary.
-->
```

e.g. you might need a manager-gui role. However, due to my abstinence of using this app, I'm not 100% sure that this is indeed the case, `manager` might be sufficient.

The other common problem is something that you don't mention: `tomcat-users.xml` will only be read once at startup. If you change it while tomcat runs, you need to restart tomcat in order to pick up the changes - or configure a different realm that uses a proper database. tomcat-users.xml is just a quick-and-dirty implementation of a realm, that's not really good for production use IMHO (unless limitations like this are fine for you).

Comment: Thanks alot, this helped! In my case, firstly, I needed to add "manager-gui". Secondly, I didn't restart tomcat after adding new roles. So after adding the necessary lines and restarting tomcat everything works like a charm. All in all "manager-gui" helped me to access manager app and server status. However, if you want access host manager, you have to add "admin-gui" as well. "Manager" and "admin" roles are not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the **manager-gui** role. This would work

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
  Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
  contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
  this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
  The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
  (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
  the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License.
-->
<tomcat-users xmlns="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml tomcat-users.xsd"
              version="1.0">



  <role rolename="tomcat"/>
  <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
  <user username="tomcat" password="password1" roles="tomcat, manager-gui"/>
 
 

</tomcat-users>
```